# Как соединится с базой данных opencart

Tags: php, opencart

На сайте есть скрипт обработчик, при попытке соединится через mysql_connect ничего не получается. Скрипт лежит просто в корневой папке. Можно ли как то установить соединение с базой без создания модуля для опенкарт?

Comment: расширение `mysql` удалено в версии `php 7.0` и помечено устаревшим в версии `5.4`, возможно проблема именно в этом. настоятельно рекомендую использовать `PDO` или `mysqli`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что расширение `mysql` удалено в версии `php 7.0` и помечено устаревшим в версии `5.4`, если вы используете `php` выше `5.3`, настоятельно рекомендую использовать `PDO` или `mysqli`, так-как проблема, именно в этом.